# Probably easy vector calc question. two planes

Tags: vectors

Find the vector, or point orthogonal to plane 5x+3y+2y=0 and plane 5x+3y+2z=38 from point (0,0,0)

I have been playing with things for 2 hours.

*update* Sorry, I don't come  here often. So, I had a few ideas.

One, I was playing with the distance equation such that
$$ \frac{|Ax+By+Cz+D|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}} = Distance$$   but they wanted an exact vector on the plane.

So I was assuming that I should find an orthogonal vector to that point.  Now I know the Vectors $$ P(5,3,2) and P_0(0,0,0) $$ So all I would have to do is find an n vector such that 
$$  \vec{n} (dot) (P-P_0) = 0 $$  but I have no idea how to incorporate 38 into it.  I am so confused. I am not sure why

Comment: don't play; tell us what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal vector (vector orthogonal to the plane) of $5x+3y+2z=0$ and $5x+3y+2z=38$ is $(5,3,2)$.

So, a vector orthogonal to the planes that begins in $(0,0,0)$ is $(5,3,2)$.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: I thought it would be extremely simple. but I still don't fully understand....how does a plane and an orthogonal vector equal?

Comment: Read the answer again and tell me what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: So a plane is (5,3,2) but a vector in the plane would also be (5,3,2) would it not? so, how does an orthogonal vector of a plane, lie in the plane?

Comment: The normal vector of a plane never lies in that same plane. What exactly was your original question?

Comment: Omg, Okay, I just realized what I wasn't doing right.  My original question was what is the length.  but it turned into why does orthogonal vector have the same coeffecients as the plane.  
But wait, how does 38 get involved in this?

Comment: The $38$ is just part of the equation, it has no concrete meaning.

Comment: Wouldn't the distance or point of interest change if the number was increased?

Comment: No. :) Please click the checkbox if you thought my answer was helpful.